# pass data($post) to php file using javascript without callback

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to pass data from HTML page to PHP page But without data callback ....

i'm used two method but One of them did not succeed

1)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'phpexample.php',
    data: {voteid: x },
    success: function(data)
    {
        alert("success! X:" + data);
    }
});
```

2)

```
$.post("getClassStudent.php",
{
},
function(data){
    $("#div_id.php").html(data);

    }
);
```

Comment: Hey @Ammar Abbasi. Welcome to S.O. It's not clear what you're trying to ask here. What you mean when you say "*without data callback*"? Please review your question to explain better what you're trying to achieve. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to improve your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Thank you @Equalsk  I really needed to pass data from html page to php using javascript and without return the results to the html page ..." I want results in php page " ...why? because There would be a problem when the user press back bottom in browser

Comment: For method #2 you are not passing any data, `$.post( url, {}` you probably want this instead `$.post( url, {voteid: x}` judging by #1, `$.post` is essentially a shorthand version for `$.ajax({ type:'post'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as i can understand, you just want to send info to a php script and don't need the response, is that right?

try this

```
$.post("phpexample.php", {voteid:x});
```

or simply remove the "succes" function from the equation if you feel more confortable using $.ajax instead of $.post

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'phpexample.php',
    data: {voteid: x }
});
```

your fisrt example is correct, the second is not well formed.

more info:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

EDIT: to help you some more :)

```
<button type="button" id="element-id">click</button>

<button type="button" class="class-name">Click</button>

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    //if you are marking ans element by class use '.class-name'
    $(".class-name").click(function(){ 
       $.post("getClassStudent.php"); 
    }); 
    //if marking by id element use '#id-name'
    $("#element-id").click(function(){ 
       $.post("getClassStudent.php"); 
    }); 
});
```

be carefful with the markings, for debuggin try to use "console.log()" or "alert()" so you can see where is the problem and where the code crushes.

Comment: Any jquery version must be used?? because i using 1.5.1 ,but                  $.post( "test.php" ); not work

Comment: if possible, try to use the latest 1.11, it's allways a good idea to use the latest versions, if still doesn't work, post here your full code so i can try to cath the problemk with it

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function(){
     
   
       $("#class").click(function(){

           
   
   

        $.post("getClassStudent.php");
    });
   
});

</script>

Comment: watch my edit, so you can understan where maybe your problem is

Answer (score 0):

```
var formData = {
  'voteid'              : 'x',
};
$.ajax({
    type        : 'POST', 
    url         : 'phpexample.php', 
    data        : formData, // our data object
    dataType    : 'json', 
    encode      : true
 }).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
 });
```

Comment: That will post data to the phpexamiple, within the php file you can access it as $_POST[]; 

I have set this to expect to return a json data type.